# Unique four-regular, simple planar graph such that every face is bounded by three edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, graph-isomorphism

A question on my graph theory exam asked us to find how many $4$-regular, simple planar graphs there are up to isomorphism such that every face, including the outer face, is bounded by three edges.

I was only able to draw one such graph while trying to solve this question, and it looks like this:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

My answer that there was only one such graph was correct. Thankfully it was multiple choice, because I'm still not sure how to give a proof of this. I was wondering what a proof of this would look like. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $n$-vertex, $m$-edge planar graphs with $n$ at least $3$, you have the inequality $m \le 3n-6$. This inequality is tight when the planar graph is a maximal planar graph: a triangulation. That's what is going on here, so we know that $m=3n-6$ for this graph.

Knowing that the graph is $4$-regular gives us another relation between $m$ and $n$, and together those can be used to show that $n=6$ is the only possibility.

Finally, there is only one $4$-regular graph on $6$ vertices up to isomorphism (to see this, note that its complement is a $1$-regular graph on $6$ vertices) and it happens to be planar.

Comment: okay, cool. I didn't know that inequality was tight when you had a maximal planar graph. Thank you.